# What's the difference between adding scripts in the /etc/cron.daily/ or editing in your script in crontab(-e)?

Tags: linux, security, cron

There are multiple options - with cron - to start your script at a specific time, but is one more secure over the other?

My question is simple:

> What's the difference between adding scripts in the `/etc/cron.daily/` or editing in your script in `crontab(-e)`?

What I'm worried about is that other users are able to see the content. I want to make sure that nobody but root can view the crontab, whether it be in the `/etc/cron.daily/` or the user's crontab.

Are other users able to see what's in `/etc/cron.daily/` or the crontab, which you can see with `crontab -l`?

I'm always logged as root in a particular server. I just need to know who/what/when about crons, so that I can choose wisely when implementinig cron jobs.

I'm using CentOS 6.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system-wide scripts in `/etc/cron*` are world-readable by default. For example, on my Arch:

```
$ ls -ld /etc/cron*
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 31  2015 /etc/cron.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 31  2015 /etc/cron.daily
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   74 May 31  2015 /etc/cron.deny
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 31  2015 /etc/cron.hourly
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 31  2015 /etc/cron.monthly
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 31  2015 /etc/cron.weekly
```

And:

```
$ ls -l /etc/cron.d/0hourly 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 128 May 31  2015 /etc/cron.d/0hourly
```

User-specific cron files are in `/var/spool/cron` by default and they, at least on my system, are not world-readable:

```
$ ls -l /var/spool/cron/
total 8
-rw------- 1 root   root   20 Feb 23 16:34 root
-rw------- 1 terdon terdon 22 Feb 23 16:32 terdon
```

So, the "safest" way would be to use the user's crontab, the one you get with `crontab -e`. Normal users can't read that:

```
$ cat /var/spool/cron/root 
cat: /var/spool/cron/root: Permission denied
```

I suggest you check and make sure this is also the case on your CentOS first though, I don't have access to a CentOS machine at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

On `/etc/cron.daily/` you have the user (as first field), so it can run cronjob of any user.  AFAIK it is the only difference.

The `/etc/cron.daily/` has the advantage of backups and deployment. The files in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` (used by `cronttab -e` are more prone to be overwritten.